# Ionic 4 - Getting [ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1) when I run "ionic server"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am struggling in this error when I try the first run on an **Ionic4** project.

> ng run app:serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100
>
> [ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).
>
> ```
>   The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
> ```

I'm using Linux Elementary OS (a nice distro that came from Ubuntu).

I tried to run a **ionic3** project and it ran successfully.

When I run ionic serve --verbose I get this message

[image]

I already tried many things, "npm cache clean", reinstall node, reinstall ionic, start/stop nodejs process. But without any success.
As I am not finding anyone with the exactly same problem as mine I am asking you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my version of NodeJS and JDK.

I used "nvm use 8.12.0" to point to supported node version. Also I have to change the version of my JDK, I used openJDK 8.

Comment: Could you elaborate/provide more information please.

Comment: Hi could you please elaborate more regarding the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Re-install below package...

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

[And just change PATHEXT if there is space or ; at last then remove it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irCK0.png)

Comment: This package is deprecated, it's no longer recommended to use it

Answer (score 2):

1: open your project root folder

2: delete node_modules folder

3: run `npm install`

This solution worked... i hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I got error when I run my ionic serve, the ionic command line interface (CLI) will exit.
So first I delete my node_modules folder, but it is not resolved.

Finally, it is resolved to run the command line below I mentioned:

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

It requires to Specify the type
Run the below command

```
ionic start myApp tabs --type=ionic1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
npm cache clean --force
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli

npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

Comment: Please add some description why do you suggest this answer.

Comment: it will re-install the updated version of angular and ionic cli

Answer (score 1):

Run this code.

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I copied my files from the original folder they were created in, into a new folder, then I got that error. But if I served it from it's original folder, it worked first time.

I also made sure I had the latest npm and node installed.

Answer (score 0):

at first you have to delete node module folder from your project.

then run below command

```
npm cache clean --force
```

after that run

```
npm i
```

finally, now you can run

```
ionic serve
```

Comment: same problem [ERROR] react-scripts has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible that while creating this Ionic project/app it got hint with internet issues or network related trouble which didnt install all the needed dependencies?

Try creating a branch new ionic project then cd into it and run ionic serve to see if all goes smooth.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I known your problem was solved but also you can apply the following command 
 in your terminal

> npm cache clean --force 
> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
> npm uninstall  -g @ionic/cli

---

you can also delete packatges with the alternative **path:- C:\Users\user_Name\AppData\Roaming**

in Roaming folder delete npm folder
it removes all packages which you previously install (angular/ionic etc.)

and now last  reinstall all the dependencies

> npm install -g @angular/cli
> npm install  -g @ionic/cli

Answer (score 0):

install angular first than create ionic project this is solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend of your error:

`[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).`

Just tell you, that it can't run the server, you need to watch the error like it told:

`The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.`

For me it throw error while in `(phase:setup)`

Then you just car read it:

```
throw new Error("Depend of your error")
Error: Depend of your error
```

After finding this line, you can search in stackoverflow or google how solve the error.

For me it was a missing dependencies, and I just install it:

```
Error: The target entry-point "@ionic-native/file" has missing dependencies:
- @ionic-native/core
```

solved with:

`npm i @ionic-native/core`

Answer (score 0):

run the below command, Proxy can be enabled by default!!:

```
ionic config unset proxy -g
```

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/4454