# ionic serve has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127)

Tags: ionic-framework

> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
>   [ng] An unhandled exception occurred: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
>   [ng] See "C:\Users\Ashwin\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-WujacN\angular-errors.log" for further details.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127).

```
    The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Comment: Hi, @ASHWIN have you found solution to this issue?

Comment: Duplicate of this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885720/ionic-4-getting-error-ng-has-unexpectedly-closed-exit-code-1-when-i-run-i