# ionic serve command failed to find argument

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an angular project and I want to use ionic for mobile. I did `ionic init`.

When I run the command `ionic serve`, I get this error:

```
> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
[ng] Error: Unknown arguments: host, port

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Here is my `package.json` :

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --configuration production",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.4",
    "angular-material-dynamic-themes-eli": "^1.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "flag-icons": "^6.4.4",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-editor": "^15.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.23",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.4.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  }
}
```

How can I fix the host/port missing arguments ?

After a comment of [SimpleDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17569309), I tried all answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52885720/10952503) :

- Use `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev` : The `@ionic/app-scripts` package is deprecated and not updated to angular 14 or 15. When running it, I get `Undefined variable standalone_static_library in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp`.
- Delete `node_modules` and `npm install`: Doesn't change anything
- Uninstall and reinstall angular/ionic cli [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67002013/10952503) : Already tried, and didn't change anything
- Multiple answer are copied, and others are the same: doesn't works

Comment: do you have the `https://nodejs.org/en/` lts version installed? since the error mentions that host not found and usually nodejs creates the host and not ionic (angular), ionic (angular) just points to the host but not them who create it.. so check your node js if installed and if it is installed check if its all working (do searches for this point) since sometimes npm works and not the full fuctionalities of it so make sure from node js you can create a server then you can get if the problem is from nodejs or not..

Comment: @MostafaHarb Yes, I think I've got here, how can I check ? I'm using node v18.7.0. Also, nodejs works to run typescript discord bot, idk if it's helping. Update: I just update nodeJs version to v18.12.1 from official release and I get the exact same issue

Comment: Do any of these solutions help you? [Ionic 4 - Getting [ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885720/ionic-4-getting-error-ng-has-unexpectedly-closed-exit-code-1-when-i-run-i)

Comment: @SimpleDev after trying those answer, it seems I've got an issue as `python2` command doesn't work, even if I have python2.7 installed (can use it with `py -2.7`)

Comment: @SimpleDev I tried, and I just edited my post for a complete answer

Comment: Start a new ionic 6 project. copy your angular code there.
OR to add support of ionic to an already angular project use `ng add @ionic/angular`

Comment: @FidaKhattak it didn't change anything

Answer (score 4):

I have been able to fix this issue for a project I'm working on, after experiencing just this issue. It seems that the **app** part in `app:serve` is dynamic and relates to the name of your angular project as defined in angular.json. The `ionic` CLI tool seems to assume this is always **app**, even though the installer has added quite a few `ng` commands to angular.json using the project name it found in this same angular.json file. What fixed the issue for me is renaming the project to `app` by editing the angular.json config:

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myapp": {
      "projectType": "application",
```

In the above example,`myapp` should be changed to `app`. Search for other occurrances of `myapp` as well, you'll find a few `myapp:build,` myapp:serve`, etc. commands as well. Those should be renamed as well.

Now, when I run `ionic serve` I get no errors and the Angular server actually starts.

Comment: This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of renaming the app or changing the script (which didn't work for me) I updated the `ionic.config.json`:

the `<app-name>` value was incorrect for me, it was `app`. So I changed it to the correct name `app-name`.

```
{
  "defaultProject": "app-name",
  "projects": {
    "app-name": {
      "name": "app-name",
      "type": "angular"
    }
  }
}
```

Now `ionic capacitor run android -l` runs as expected.

Comment: What did you change? The `capacitor`?

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was specifying the project name as you would in the angular cli with

`ionic serve --project {{project}}`

Comment: This is a valid and working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Leon Boot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74840590/9043524) I added a script to my package.json to run it my application. I didn't want to rename my application.

The *ionic serve* command is itself just a script that outputs as:

```
 ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
```

The *app* part is just the name of the application that it's going to serve.
I tried finding some config file setting for ionic that controls this value, but I didn't find anything in the documentation for [ionic serve](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/serve), or the [configuration file](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuration).

I worked around this limitation by making my own script.
I copied the output from the *ionic serve* command, to a script and changed app to the name of my application.
Now my packages.json file has this "ionic:serve" script:

```
 {
  "name": "my-application-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "ionic:serve": "ng.cmd run my-application-name:serve --host=localhost --port=8100"
  },...
```

For your application replace *my-application-name* with the name of your  application.

Now run this script instead using *ionic serve*:

```
npm run ionic:serve
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution can help you:

1. npm cache clean --force
2. npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
3. npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli
4. npm install -g @angular/cli
5. npm install -g @ionic/cli

Comment: I got the exact same error :/

Comment: are you trying this solution?!

Comment: Yes I tried your solution, but nothing changed

Comment: If I don't get any other answer, even if it's not working, to don't lose them, I will give you the +100 rep bounty

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple and easy way i do every project of angular for ionic.

1. Create new ionic project with `ionic start projectName`
2. Delete src folder of ionic
3. Copy paste src of angular
4. Install angular module you want to install on the ionic project

If you want run ionic project on angular project it has a lot of error